# Браузер увеличивает media запросы css

Tags: css, media-queries

Запрос на изменение данных css исходит из max-width 1330px. Всё отлично работало во всех браузерах, но как-то заметил, что яндекс браузер увеличивает сам по себе этот max-width 1330px.
С чем может быть связано?
Приложил изображение, где файл открыт в двух разных браузерах (слева яндекс (неверное отображение), а справа google (как должно быть).
У яндекса свои какие-то предустановки?
Папка на github`e https://github.com/GamaRayL/cv.git
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: масштаб страницы небось не 100%

Comment: Да, невнимательность она такая. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже выше упомянули, в пользовательских настройках браузера масштаб страницы может быть может быть измененный (Ctrl + ±). Может проблема в настройке тега meta (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`). Деректива `:root` в css (хотя и тянется с бутстрапа), или на крайний случай попробуйте небольшие файлики вроде [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) или reset. Перепроверьте стили в DevTools, или поочередно отключите ваши css. И раз уж мы тут... подключайте скрипты внизу, перед закрывающем тегом `</body>`, как например советуют [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template). Фух, ну и ничего конкретного. Ахах. Не знаю.

Comment: Самое интересное так это то, что браузер сохраняет масштаб при выходе из него и заходе и точечно на страницу, не показывая масштаб. Да уж. Спасибо.
В масштабе дело.

Comment: Спасибо за совет по скриптам.